# Remove all e-mail properties from users document in Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

[image]

(Removed data for privacy purposes)
I have thousands of users with their emails stored in firebase database, I want to remove all the `email` properties in them. What is the safest way to do it without doing it one by one?

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to take advantage of the import export feature of the RTDB console:

[image]

Export the data as JSON, modify the JSON data with the method of your choice, delete all the data in the database, import the modified JSON.

Comment: What if someone signs up in the process of it? I thought of this but I don't think it's the optimal solution since it replaces all the existing data

Comment: "What if someone signs up in the process of it?" => Obviously, this is a maintenance action, you should probably close the access (Security rules and error message in the front end?) while processing.

Answer (score 1):

You can only delete a value from the database by writing to its entire path. So you must by definition perform a write operation to each user node.

But for a couple of thousand users that actually is not too big a deal. In JavaScript:

```
let ref = firebase.database().ref("/users");
let query = ref.orderByChild("email").startAt(null);
return query.once("value").then((results) => {
  let updates = {};
  results.forEach((snapshot) => {
    updates[snapshot.key+"/email"] = null;
  });
  return ref.update(updates);
})
```

The above code:

- Finds all users who have an email address.
- Build an object that clears the email address for each of those users.
- Sends a single write operation to the database for all users.

You can run this code in either a JavaScript client, as a Node script using the Admin SDK, or in Cloud Functions (in which case it'll also use the Admin SDK).

---

Of you have too many nodes to update, you can also try updating them in batches, or one by one as with this code:

```
let ref = firebase.database().ref("/users");
let query = ref.orderByChild("email").startAt(null);
return query.once("value").then((results) => {
  let promises = []
  results.forEach((snapshot) => {
    promises.push(snapshot.ref.child("email").remove());
  });
  return Promise.all(promises);
})
```

Comment: I just tried this and it worked very smoothly, by the way. Thank you so much.

Comment: ...It worked very smoothly on a small test document I created. Now I'm getting `TOO_MANY_TRIGGERS` error, probably because of... too many triggers. Trying to find a solution now.

Comment: I was wondering, how are you doing forEach on results when results is an object? I tried this in node playground and it didn't work, but your above code didn't throw any error that forEach on results can't be applied, and when I logged results, it's an object that I built a similar one just for testing, and the test failed. I'm confused.

Comment: `results is a `DataSnapshot`, which is a class from the Firebase SDK. If you're having a hard time making it work, edit your question to show what you tried please.

Comment: No this worked perfectly (second section of your answer, `Promise.all()` one), I was just wondering why manually trying `forEach` on an object didn't work but it did work on `results` object.